# Gnome software can't uninstall any software: no packages to remove

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gnome-shell, ubuntu-unity, ubuntu-22.04

I'm on ubuntu 22.04 lts and I have a problem with gnome-software 41.5 and gnome-software-plugin-flatpak, the problem is that Gnome software is able to install software and update the system but when I press the uninstall button to uninstall a software I get a message that says: "Cannot remove software: no packages to remove", and I noticed that other ubuntu derivatives that use gnome-software by default also have this problem.
Is there a way to fix this and get gnome-software to work properly?

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this same issue with the Chirp application on PureOS. Installed fine, but cannot remove.

[image]

App is not listed from flatpak command line util, but it has an XDG icon and launches. I did a `dpkg -l | grep chirp` command and found that the apt package was installed. I was able to remove it with this command

```
sudo apt purge chirp
```

Comment: Had same issue and this worked for me. Wonder whether it's something about PureOS. I noticed they also had some (extensions, tweaks, system tray disabled which I needed to actually use the Breaktimer app), once I figured all those things out, I could cleanly install it and use it, but this post helped me uninstall it first.